# how to convert the value of nsarray to integer value

Tags: iphone, nsarray, tableview, nsinteger

I working on grouped table view based work in that in that i want to convert the value of NSarray into integer for specifing to section value of numberOfRowsInSection but it throws expection on putting following code.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

 int sec;
 if (section == 0){ sec=6; }
 else if(section == 1){ sec=6; }
 else if(section == 2){ 
 sec=[[rsvn_detail objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"totalrecord"];
 }
 return sec;
}
```

Anybody help to recify it advance thanks for your suggestion

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSArray and NSDictionary can only hold Objective-C objects. An `int` is not an object. It is likely the number is wrapped as an NSNumber. To convert an NSNumber back to an `int`, call `-intValue`:

```
 sec = [[[rsvn_detail objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"totalrecord"] intValue];
 //                                                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

Of course, make sure `rsvn_detail` is really an NSArray of NSDictionary. Without `-intValue` won't cause exceptions, only compiler warning/error will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exception? Seems that

```
[[rsvn_detail objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"totalrecord"];
```

is causing the problem.